# Complicated NSPredicates: comparing values on the most-recent object

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I've got a complicated predicate I'm trying to work out.

Basically, I have a Student object. Students have testScoreObjects. A TestScoreObject has properties such as scoreDate (NSDate) and score (NSNumber).

I'd like a list of students whose most recent (by scoreDate) TestScoreObject's score is greater than n.

Ideally it would be great to accomplish this is one NSPredicate on a NSFetchedResultsController.

I know how to accomplish this programmatically by going through all of the students, but I'm wondering if this is possible to do with a predicate so I can keep all of the wonderful benefits of having a FetchedResultsController.

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following predicate:

```
NSString *format = @"SUBQUERY(testScoreObjects, $each, $each.score > $n && $each.scoreDate == testScoreObjects.@max.scoreDate)[SIZE] > 0";
NSDictionary *substitutions = @{@"n": @3}; // 3 is the value for n
NSPredicate *predicate = [[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:format] predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:substitutions];
```

or

```
NSString *format = @"ANY SUBQUERY(testScoreObjects, $each, $each.score > $n).scoreDate == testScoreObjects.@max.scoreDate";
NSDictionary *substitutions = @{@"n": @3}; // 3 is the value for n
NSPredicate *predicate = [[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:format] predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:substitutions];
```

Both worked correctly to filter an array but I haven't tested whether CoreData is able to translate them to SQL (so it can be used with a fetch request).

When dealing with a large store, the second predicate *should* be more efficient (as far as I know) because `testScoreObjects.@max.scoreDate` is evaluated only once per student. Of course, actual results may differ.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Those indeed did work when filtering arrays, but Core Data really doesn't like @max. Oh well, we'll find another way!

Answer (score 0):

Subqueries are really a SQL-inherited crutch when it comes to object graphs. I think you can do without that. Have a look at how simple things can be:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
     @"ANY testScores.scoreDate > %@", cutoffDate];
```